# How to get out of infinite loop for ROBIRG's maze when the "right_is_clear" for next four position?

Tags: if-statement, while-loop

```
def turn_right():
    turn_left()
    turn_left()
    turn_left()
```

#Roborgs maze is (5,5)
#Roborgs position and face of direction will be random in a maze.

```
while not at_goal():       #till the robot reaches the goal this loop continues running
    if right_is_clear():   #roborgs check whether the right side is clear or not? If yes, turn right  
        turn_right()
        move()             #problem is this maze has four positions where there is no wall on the right side, when the roborgs are being placed at that position, the loop gets infinite. Position are (4,3) , (4,4) , (3,3) , (3,4).
    elif front_is_clear():
        move()
    else:
        turn_left()   
        if wall_in_front():
            turn_left()
        else:
            move()
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this is old and I'm not sure how optimized it is, but this is what I came up with to not get caught in a loop:

```
def turn_right():
    turn_left()
    turn_left()
    turn_left()
def find_goal():
    if right_is_clear() == True:
            turn_right()
            move()
        if right_is_clear() == True:
                turn_right()
                move()
            if right_is_clear() == True:
                    turn_right()
                    move()
                if right_is_clear() == True:
                    if front_is_clear() == True:
                        move()
                    else:
                        turn_left()
    elif front_is_clear() == True:
        move()
    else:
            turn_left()
        if front_is_clear() == True:
            move()
        else:
            turn_left()
            move()
while not at_goal():
    find_goal()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?